# Guidelines for the use of the slang term "cise"

Tags: slang, dialects, word-usage

I heard an unfamiliar regional slang word used thusly:

> I'm gonna go cise (rhymes with ice) me a sandwich and then I'll be back.

When I questioned the user, the speaker insisted it has been around a few years at least, and that it has to do with overdoing something and something that makes one happy.  [According to Urban Dictionary, def 2](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cise), it is a regional slang for my area. And according to def 4:

> word used when asking for something in place of whatever other verb one would use.

It looks like it means everything.  I've attempted using this term in response, but kept getting corrected.  What am I missing? Are there guidelines<sup>1</sup> to use the word *cise* (at least in the DC area)?
<sub>1: By *guidelines*, I mean in order to use the term idiomatically, what contexts are not allowed, and for what terms can or cannot the word be used as a substitute</sub>

Comment: +1 and an interesting question. I hope you find an answer. I don't see anything beyond UD, but one of the entries there suggests it might be a contraction of "precisely" ... but Urban Dictionary is rather the opposite of precise, in my opinion, although it can point toward the truth. It's like a shotgun: a good weapon if you're not too fussy.

Comment: I come from Virginia, and I never heard it either...

Comment: Is it possible that it relates to "da kine" -- a Hawai'ian pidgin word that stands in for a word that doesn't come to mind or is implicit (i.e., "you know what I mean")?

Comment: How is it pronounced? Does it sound like "seize?"

Comment: @Cody: See the edit to my answer below for correct pronunciation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this from the blog [everynothing](http://buffalorome.blogspot.com/2009/01/mornings.html) (though his use of it seems not to fit his defintion):

> I recently sent a text message to my friend that read "I was tryna cop some jont and my man cised me. You tryna chill for a minute?" He responded "Dank dank." This conversation never actually happened, but it totally could have. I have realized that my friends and I converse in a language all our own. It is not like a sneaky drug code. That conversation could have been about anything from pot to sandwiches. When I write I avoid using this crazy vernacular, but I'd like to take a moment here to introduce and maybe analyze the etymology of the way we speak.
>
> **Tryna**- Literally means trying to. It could be sexual (are you tryna with that girl?) or platonic (I'mma go to six flags. You tryna?)
>
> **Jont**- Pretty much any noun. It literally could mean anything. (Lemme see that jont. I'm tryna get some jont. Where's my jont?) Jont is a strange mutation of the word joint I think. (also Jank Jams Janx-A-lanx Jiggidy-Jont Jontpiece)
>
> **Finna**- Literally fixing to, it's like tryna but it can't stand alone. You can say I'm tryna but not I'm finna unless finna has an object
>
> **Cise** - To give (Cise me that jont) I can't even explain where that came from. . .

**Edit, 5/15/11**:

Did some more sleuthing and may have narrowed it down some. I noticed the adjective *[cised](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cised)* listed at Urban Dictionary (UD) as well. Among other explanations of it being slang for "overjoyed" was this:

> a word used entirely too much by the 99.1 WHFS Sports Junkies (Radio DJ's in DC)

Since this matches the geography found so far on *cise*, and since UD's entries on *cised* predate its entries on *cise*, I think it's safe to assume that the verb *to cise* came from the earlier adjective *cised*.

Following the Sports Junkies lead, I found *cised* used [136 times](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=cised%20site:junks.tv&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on their [official website](http://junks.tv/) and *cise* used [twice](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=cise%20site:junks.tv&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I then found their official definition of *cised*, complete with pronunciation guide, on their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=2204505943&v=info) :

> **Cised**
> To be excited; (occasionally) sexually aroused. If used in a phrase such as "cised for [something]," it can simply mean that the speaker likes the thing in question. The word is pronounced with a soft "s" (as in 'side' or 'psychology') and rhymes with "iced", rather than with "excised" or "prized." This term is commonly preceded by the word “butt-” which may amplify the phrase to mean extremely excited.

UD users attribute the Sports Junkies with coining and popularizing [several other slang words and phrases](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sports%20junkies) including *grasper*, *work your trick*, *money metal*, *Lou Holtz* and *hogsmoke*. Given this, and the popularity this show had in the D.C. Metro area, I'll put my money on the Junkies as original disseminators, and possible coiners, of the word.

Comment: A while ago, a friend who was in the DC Go-go community and a musician, knew of an old 1982 song that uses the term.  Link here, with the therm at 3 min 50 sec: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3rXo4O5Fbs

Answer (score 6):

From what a little research turned up, it appears to be **student slang**, but not specifically local. As featured in [an article on the *Churchill Observer*](http://www.thechurchillobserver.com/features/2010/03/01/no-cise-student-language-is-starting-to-blow-up/):

> **[cise]** Its also open-ended definition is what attracts students. *“Cise”* has been defined by sites such as Urban Dictionary to mean exaggeration and many users follow that listing. But there are still other ways to use it; one way is to say that somebody did something nice for you. For example *“My teacher cised me that A,”* or *“He cised me his sandwich at lunch.”* Additionally, *“cise”* is used to imply that one wants someone to give them something, “Cise me my jacket,” or that they did well on an assignment, *“I just cised that test.”*

Blogs [here](http://akinokure.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-tell-that-youre-old.html) and [there](http://buffalorome.blogspot.com/2009/01/mornings.html) also discuss its meaning, but in all cases, it seems at odds with your quote. I could find no reported use of cising *oneself*.

Comment: It's about an hour I'm searching about it but no special results. You might have ate Google. ;)

Comment: The similar use to "to hit someone up with" from the first linked blog helps greatly.  Thank you.

Comment: The _Churchill Observer_ is a student paper from a D.C. suburb high school, blogger #1 seems to be from D.C. and blogger #2 writes about Delaware. I think it is still regional slang.